# spring unable jsp file in vscode

Tags: java, spring, jsp, visual-studio-code

My IDE is VSCODE

tomcat server is connected normally
but controller not working
404 error appears when entering "http://localhost:8080/sp5-chap09/hello?name=abc"
The controller's println does not work, so the console does not see log

When i access "http://localhost:8080/sp5-chap09/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/hello.jsp", the jsp file displays in the browser and no 404 error occurs, but parameters cannot be imported

---

**workspace tree:**

```
SP5-CHAP09
|   pom.xml
|
+---src
|   \---main
|       +---java
|       |   +---chap09
|       |   |       HelloController.java
|       |   |
|       |   \---config
|       |           ControllerConfig.java
|       |           MvcConfig.java
|       |
|       +---resources
|       \---webapp
|           \---WEB-INF
|               |   web.xml
|               |
|               \---view
|                       hello.jsp
|
\---target
    +---classes
    |   +---chap09
    |   |       HelloController.class
    |   |
    |   \---config
    |           ControllerConfig.class
    |           MvcConfig.class
    |
    +---generated-sources
    |   \---annotations
    +---maven-archiver
    |       pom.properties
    |
    +---maven-status
    |   \---maven-compiler-plugin
    |       \---compile
    |           \---default-compile
    |                   createdFiles.lst
    |                   inputFiles.lst
    |
    \---test-classes
```

---

**controller:**

```
package chap09;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(Model model,
            @RequestParam(value="name", required=false) String name){
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello, " + name);

        System.out.println("hello() method execute: " + LocalDateTime.now());

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

---

**config file:**

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import chap09.HelloController;

@Configuration
public class ControllerConfig {
    @Bean
    public HelloController helloController(){
        return new HelloController();
    }
}
```

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry){
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/view/", ".jsp");
    }
}
```

---

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>sp5</groupId>
    <artifactId>sp5-chap09</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>utf-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                config.MvcConfig
                config.ControllerConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

**view file:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        greeting: ${greeting}
    </body>
</html>
```

---

I searched, but there was no solution that fits me
I can't guess

Comment: Check that you can access the Tomcat welcome page(*http://localhost:8080/*) to verify that the application is properly deployed to Tomcat. Also provides a detailed error log.

Comment: i can access the tomcat welcome page(localhost:8080).
there is no problem running Tomcat.
no other error logs other than 404.
controller's system.out.println is not logged.

Comment: Check tomcat logs and web.xml configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

1. When you work on maven, the maven project task line is created at the bottom left of vscode.
2. If you click the task line, the maven projects in the workspace appear as a list.
3. Among them, right-click the directory you want to operate, and select 'package' from the list that appears.
4. A maven-war-plugin version error occurred.
5. Added maven-war-plugin 3.2.2 in pom.xml.
6. If you select 'package' again, a war file is created in the target folder.
7. Add the war file created in the tomcat server.
8. If you do show in browser, the maven project works normally.
9. You must click 'package' every time you edit the code.